# MS Graph API rejects token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create a node.js service to access my user's calendar and send invites to others through MS Graph API.

Therefor I followed this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

```
const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/oauth2/token";
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "[appid]",
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    client_secret: "[password/secret]"
};

request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    }
    else {
        //console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);         
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
            requestData(parsedBody.access_token)
        }
    }
});

function requestData(accessToken) {
    request.get({
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

I could successfully retrieve an access token but when I try to request any of the Graph APIs I receive an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "..",
      "date": "2019-02-17T09:44:09"
    }
  }
}
```

Any hints what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting this error as in your code you are trying to get the access token by sending the token request to `/[tenant]/oauth2/token` endpoint.  As per the documentation which you are following you need to send the access request to V2 endpoint which is `/[tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/token`.